# Azure Websites, Can one deploy .NET 4.5.1 websites?

Tags: azure

I notice that Azure Websites seems to offer .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.5. So I assume that one cannot deploy .NET 4.5.1 web applications yet?

I mention this as .NET 4.5.1 seems to have a useful new feature called "ASP.NET app suspension" which seems to pull back app images much more quickly into RAM. Perhaps Although this feature is targeted at hosters, one wonders whether this is a solution to the "Warm Up" issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions here.

1) Azure Web Sites does support .NET 4.5.1, as in the update is installed on all Azure Web Site VMs.  This has been available for several months now.  So when you select 4.5, you are really running 4.5.1.  The version reading "4.5" in the portal is misleading, unfortunately, and due to the fact the 4.5.1 upgrade did not change major/minor versions of framework so the "4.5" remains.

2) The specific "ASP.NET application suspension feature" unfortunately is part of a .NET 4.5.1 version that only ships in Windows 8.1/Server 2012R2.  Azure Web Sites VMs currently only run Server 2012.  Therefore ASP.NET application suspension is not supported in Azure Web Sites.

Azure Web Sites does other things to attempt to manage cold start performance issues (such as aggressive caching of compiled assemblies) but this is certainly a feature we would like to add in a future version of WAWS.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Huge thanks for the comment. It is great to hear directly from the "top". We are startup and have been having significant problems with Warmup performance issues. App pools can recycle for odd reasons, not least for being idle. So, at least, one is forced to auto ping to keep the site hot, which is not ideal.

Comment: regarding 1), very interesting. Does this mean that it would be advantageous to compile the web app as 4.5.1?

Comment: regarding 2) Sad. Would this out of interest solve the warm up issue that we have to auto ping against?

Comment: Can one NGen a web app's MSIL dlls for Azure Websites? Just an idea I had to get around the warm up issue.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Services supports .NET 4.5.1 
[look here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/10/18/windows-azure-announcing-support-for-windows-server-2012-r2-some-nice-price-cuts.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this, but is this just for Cloud Services and not Websites: "Cloud Services: Support for Windows Server 2012 R2 and .NET 4.5.1 "?