# Azure Websites, Can one deploy .NET 4.5.2 websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-4.5.2

From [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424847/azure-websites-can-one-deploy-net-4-5-1-websites) I see 4.5.1 is supported in WAWS and when you select 4.5, you are really running 4.5.1.

How about the [recently released](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/05/05/announcing-the-net-framework-4-5-2-release.aspx) 4.5.2 ?

Is there any official documentation anywhere on which framework updates have been applied to WAWS?

Comment: You forgot your links.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

(changing the answer now that we have updated Azure Web Sites with .NET 4.5.2)

.NET 4.5.2 is currently installed on Azure Web Sites.  So you can deploy websites which take advantage of 4.5.2 framework features.

I'm updating this answer to reflect this change.

Comment: specifically we want to use the HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem feature with StmpServer to send mail asynchronously as this will help us easily trap unhandled errors in elmah if the background process fails.

Comment: @eagle779 have you considered using WebBackgrounder (http://www.nuget.org/packages/webbackgrounder) if you're limited to 4.5.1 and below? That package was written by current and former members of the ASP.NET team, so reliability and performance characteristics should be acceptable for most applications.

Comment: .NET 4.5.2 is now installed on Azure Web Sites and is available for use.

Comment: @BilalAlam also for the Azure Web Roles?

Comment: @MatteoMigliore sadly no, not even with SDK 2.5 released yesterday

Comment: For what it's worth, I haven't been able to get my .NET 4.5.2 websites to deploy on WAWS. See this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686271/azure-websites-with-net-4-5-2.