# Azure websites .NET 4.5.2 availability date

Tags: azure-web-app-service, .net-4.5.2

Not sure of the appropriate place to ask this question.

Do you by any chance know the date when .NET 4.5.2 will be generally installed on the Azure Websites?

I seem to have run into a very curious issue - I have recently switch my application over to using HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem (only available from 4.5.2 onwards). I though I have tested it and it worked on Azure Websites (I'm 99.9999% sure that I have and it worked). I then had a demo scheduled to a potential client - and I hour before the demo I started getting the method not found exception on the pages that were using that API call.

It is currently running on a shared tier. Are all of the Azure website servers of the same patch level or could it have happened that the website was moved to a different server during one of the redeployments and that server had a different patch level? I just need to understand the behaviour - in order to avoid running into this issue in the future!

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It finally happened, .NET 4.5.2 was installed to Azure Websites.**

1. David Ebbo, Dev Lead @ Windows Azure Web Sites team [twitted on September 5, 2014](https://twitter.com/davidebbo/status/507975575688851456) the following:

   > Azure WebSites is now running .NET Framework 4.5.2 (actually for a
   >   month, but we never announced it!)
2. Bilal Alam, Partner Development Manager @ Microsoft Azure Web Workload also [confirmed it in a related thread on September 5, 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554496/azure-websites-can-one-deploy-net-4-5-2-websites#23554969):

   > .NET 4.5.2 is currently installed on Azure Web Sites. So you can
   >   deploy websites which take advantage of 4.5.2 framework features.