# What versions of .NET are supported on Azure Web Sites?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

To avoid more questions like [Azure Websites, Can one deploy .NET 4.5.1 websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424847/azure-websites-can-one-deploy-net-4-5-1-websites) and [Azure Websites, Can one deploy .NET 4.5.2 websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554496/azure-websites-can-one-deploy-net-4-5-2-websites), is there a web site that lists all the .NET Frameworks that are supported in Azure Web Sites?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't know if there's any specific blog post or reference listing, but... here's a quick-n-easy way for you to check for yourself. Note: This requires you to already have a Web Site up and running. You can spin up a new free-tier website really quickly. Then:

- Navigate to the Kudu portal for your website, at `https://yourwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net`
- Go to the **Debug Consule** menu and choose CMD or PowerShell:

][image: Kudu debug console menu options]

- Navigate to `D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework` and you'll see assembly directories for each installed framework version:

[image: .net framework versions installed]

I realize this isn't automated, but at least it's a way for you to make a quick determination. I don't know if this will always work this way, or if it's the *only* way or the *best* way. Just showing you *a* way.

Comment: Hi, does anyone know the availability date for the .NET 4.5.2 on the Azure Websites?

Comment: The above method shows .NET 4.5.2, at least it does when I tried it just now. :)

Comment: I was interested in .NET 4.6.1 due to the improved SQL Azure connectivity and I can confirm that both 4.6.1 and 4.6.2 are installed

Comment: This approach still works as of 19-june-2018.  And as of today 4.7.1 is the most recently available.