# How to use .NET framework 4.6 with Azure Websites?

Tags: .net, azure

The .NET framework 4.6 is released. I've migrated my application but when I deploy to an Azure Website I get the following error:

```
D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(983,5): warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
```

Is there any way to install or bundle this with a release?

Comment: No, it's not yet supported...

Comment: @Bidou: Do we know when it is supported?

Comment: I didn't find this information... if someone knows the answer, I'm interested too...

Comment: better wait a while http://nickcraver.com/blog/2015/07/27/why-you-should-wait-on-dotnet-46/

Comment: @Lanorkin that's good information, thanks, but also bear in mind that is a bug in the released .NET 4.6. A fix for that bug won't mean Azure Web Apps will follow immediately. It could be that on Azure will arrive sooner; but, read this article here (especially the recommendations): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/07/28/ryujit-bug-advisory-in-the-net-framework-4-6.aspx for Microsoft's take on the situation.

Comment: @davenewza There is no timescale for .NET 4.6 on Azure Web Apps - please see my answer below if you need to get live now. MS Azure Support told me to watch this for news on when 4.6 will be released on Azure Web Apps: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/topics/announcements/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-on-net-framework-4-6-and-azure/

Update (August 14, 2015) - We're happy to announce that .NET Framework 4.6 has been rolled out to Azure App Service. So Web App developers can now build and deploy ASP.NET applications running .NET Framework 4.6 to Azure Web Apps.

OUTDATED Original Answer:

According to the following blog post on MSDN:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/07/20/announcing-asp-net-4-6-and-asp-net-5-beta-5-in-visual-studio-2015-release.aspx#pub46Hosting

"Azure Web Apps Availability

With the brand-new release of ASP.NET 4.6, the Azure Web Apps service is still being prepared and tested for this important update.  Once we have confirmed that Azure Web Apps can host an ASP.NET 4.6 application with the same high level of performance and fidelity that you expect from Microsoft Azure, we will announce compatibility of the service.  Our operations team is working diligently and we will update you on the Microsoft Azure blog in the near future."

Comment: The latest blog post (from 8/11/15) says that they're expecting to roll it out sometime this month: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/08/11/update-on-net-framework-4-6-and-azure/

Comment: For those of you down voting this answer...consider it was answered on July 22...when the question was asked. Yes...the 4.6 update has been made...four weeks after this was the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

[Per David Ebbo](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/262f9f05-31b6-429d-a83a-97efc5fdb82a/net-framework-46-full-support?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview&prof=required) on the MSDN Forums, 4.6 is now supported.

> The 4.6 update is now complete. Enjoy!
>
> Note that the Azure Portal still says 4.5, and will soon be updated.
>   But that's just a string update, and 4.5 really means 4.6.

If the incorrect string bothers you and you really want to know for sure. You can verify it by opening Kudu and navigating to `D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework` to see what versions are available. For more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24149178/1152054).

Answer (score 0):

As of August 14th, .NET 4.6 is officially supported on Azure Websites (Azure Web Apps), according to this...

https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/08/11/update-on-net-framework-4-6-and-azure/

> Update (August 14, 2015) – We’re happy to announce that .NET Framework
>   4.6 has been rolled out to Azure App Service. So Web App developers can now build and deploy ASP.NET applications running .NET Framework
>   4.6 to Azure Web Apps.

Answer (score -2):

If you are tied to .NET 4.6, you can create an Azure VM (in the new portal click New | Compute | Windows Server 2012 R2 and follow on through - in old portal it is helpfully called "Virtual Machines"!) and then install .NET 4.6 to that server.

You can then deploy your .NET 4.6 website to that Virtual Machine.

It is more work and admin that an Azure Web App (and than this answer might imply) but it will get you live with 4.6 if needs be.

Comment: But please bear in mind the bug that @Lanorkin highlighted in his comment on the original Question above and Nick Craver & Mark Gravell of Stackoverlow have reported to MS but you might want to read this page first (especially the recommendations): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/07/28/ryujit-bug-advisory-in-the-net-framework-4-6.aspx