# azure internal sever error - OwinHttpModule

Tags: api, azure, owin

I have recently upgraded our web API to .net framework `4.7.2` and updated all nuget packages then after deploying to azure I get the internal server error. I have turned on the logging and looked at the log stream and found the error below:

> DynamicModule_Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule,
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_a97fda07-e3a4-4e32-a107-90f4ef0b9fca

All endpoints return `500 code`, but the token endpoint which works perfectly good. No idea how that version of owin could cause the issue for other endpoints but not the token.

When I change the framework to `4.7.1`, it works perfectly.
I have no idea how to fix the issue. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Azure WebApp only support specific `.Net Framework version` like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24149178/7073340)

**How to find the supported versions ?**

Go to your Kudo Portal and navigate to `D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework`

You can find all supported `.Net Framework version` there.

[image]

Comment: I checked and it was because 4.7.2 hasn't not been deployed yet. It seems they announce to do so in mid of Oct.